# HttpUnit HttpUnitOptions.setScriptingEnabled not working

Tags: java, maven, testing, groovy, http-unit

I do get strange error.
Here is my maven dep:

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>httpunit</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpunit</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
```

Here is my Java base class:

```
    static{
//trying to make it to work....
            HttpUnitOptions.setScriptingEnabled(false);
            HttpUnitOptions.setExceptionsThrownOnScriptError(false);
        }

        @BeforeMethod(groups = "integration")
        public void setup() throws Exception {
//not working....
            HttpUnitOptions.setScriptingEnabled(false);
            HttpUnitOptions.setExceptionsThrownOnScriptError(false);
        }


        /**
         * Sends request to servlet
         * */
        protected WebResponse sendPostRequest(String d, List<CookieBean> cookies) throws Exception{
            WebConversation wc = new WebConversation();
            setCookies(wc, cookies);
            PostMethodWebRequest post = new PostMethodWebRequest(SERVLET_URL);
            post.setParameter(TrackingServlet.PARAM_D, d);
            return wc.sendRequest(post);
        }
```

And groovy test class:

```
class CookieHandlingTest extends TrackingServletBaseTest {

    static{
        HttpUnitOptions.setScriptingEnabled(false);
        HttpUnitOptions.setExceptionsThrownOnScriptError(false);
    }

    @Test(groups = 'integration')
    void testDummyRequest(){
        HttpUnitOptions.setScriptingEnabled(false);
        HttpUnitOptions.setExceptionsThrownOnScriptError(false);
        def result = sendPostRequest("d", null)
        assertThat(result, notNullValue())
    }


}

And an error:
testDummyRequest(CookieHandlingTest)  Time elapsed: 0.558 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mozilla/javascript/Scriptable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
```

Happens when I try to send request using WebConversation:

```
return wc.sendRequest(post);
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mozilla/javascript/Scriptable
```

The jar that contains the org.mozilla.javascript.Scriptable.class is not in the classpath. Add the suitable meven dependency.

Comment: I want to disable script interpretation. http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/doc/faq.html#disable scripting

Comment: But still the used classes may have references to this and other JavaScript classes. So add the library anyway and as you have coded, disable script execution.

Comment: You are right, it helps. I supposed that disabled scripting interpretation doesn't require dependency for the scripting engine...